# Visual Trick in XAML for Silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, animation

I am trying to create a control which is basically showing a list of pictures in Silverlight, but I want the list to rotate in a sort of 2.5D way.  You can think of it as the picture in the middle is YOU, and the others are your friends on social networking site.

Here is a sketch of what I mean:

[alt text http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/6374/picturering.th.png](http://img3.imageshack.us/img3/6374/picturering.th.png)

As you click the green arrows, the pictures animate/rotate to go to the next one.

Each picture will actually be inside a nice looking 3D-ish frame like the one in the Win 7 logon screen:

[image]
<sub>(source: [softpedia.com](http://www.softpedia.com/screenshots/Windows-7-Logon-Background-Changer_1.png))</sub>

Can anyone help me understand how to write this for Silverlight?  I don't need anything exact, I just don't know where to begin doing such a complicated animation.  Also, I want to be able to imitate the border of the Win 7 logon icon if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you want is a type of "CoverFlow", typically called "Carousel". Check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/carousel.aspx) for an article to get you started.  Basically, you want to Transform your images. This shouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: Additionally you may want to look into the PlaneProjection transform that was introduced in Silverlight 3 to give it more of a 3D look. Here is a coverflow tutorial which also uses the PlaneProjection which might help: http://www.cynergysystems.com/blogs/page/josefajardo?entry=coverflow_built_using_silverlight_3